# Is there any way to call "benchmark" in the javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to understand [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/christianbach/tablesorter/master/jquery.tablesorter.js) javascript code, which extends jquery. I know calling [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) on the jquery object will add a tablesorter object to the $ object.

I want to clear the cache on a tablesorter object, something like this

```
$("#myTable").tablesorter();
$("#myTable").buildParserCache(); //so as to clear the cache. I get undefined is not a function.
$("#myTable").tablesorter().buildParserCache() //also get undefined is not a function
```

Can someone explain why this is not possible and how to clear the cache. I know I am butting up against some JS design patterns and scope rules and I would like to understand them.

```
    (function ($) {
    $.extend({
        tablesorter: new
        function () {
            var parsers = [],
                widgets = [];

            this.defaults = {
                ...
            };

            /* debuging utils */

            function benchmark(s, d) {
                log(s + "," + (new Date().getTime() - d.getTime()) + "ms");
            }

           function buildParserCache(table, $headers) {
            if (table.config.debug) {
                var parsersDebug = "";
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `buildParserCache` function is defined inside the `function ()` which starts on the fourth line of that snippet, so it will only be accessible outside the function if it is explicitly exposed - and it looks like it isn't, so that is effectively a private function.

The methods which are exposed appear to be grouped after the `/* public methods */` comment.

The `this.construct = function` function gets further exposed by this:

```
$.fn.extend({
    tablesorter: $.tablesorter.construct
});
```

so that is the function that ends up being called when `$("#myTable").tablesorter()` is called.

Comment: "if it is explicitly exposed - and it looks like it isn't" how do I expose this method?

Comment: You could add a line `this.buildParserCache = buildParserCache;` just after the `public methods` comment, then access it from outside using `$.tablesorter.buildParserCache`.